# pandas HDFStore: sql "GROUP BY" equivalent

Tags: sql, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

I am trying to translate the following SQL query to run on a large pandas HDFStore:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
JOIN (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, max(colN) as maxColN
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
) m
ON m.col1=mytable.col1 AND m.col2=mytable.col2 AND m.col3=mytable.col3
WHERE colN=maxColN
```

What would be the best way to implement this? I have indexes on `col1`, `col2`, `col3`.

Comment: Your query is not proper SQL syntax.  It will return an error, so, basically, any query string that returns an error would give a similar result.  Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the sql query to actually describe what I want to do. Basically: find the rows which contain the maximum value of colN for each (col1, col2, col3) combination.